# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'csr_matrix'

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, array-broadcasting

I want to write a sigmoid function:

```
def fn(w, x):
    return 1.0 / (np.expm1(-w.dot(x))+0.0)
```

Because -w.dot(x) is a sparse matrix, I used np.expm1() instead of np.exp(), but how to divide a float by a csr_matrix? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from spicy import sparse 
res2 = np.expm1(-w.dot(x)) 
res1 = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones(res2.shape()))
return res1/res2
```